# VBA Word: Regex replace capture group does not highlight

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, find, highlight

I cannot figure out why the code is not working. I want to find within a cell (XXX) regex match and highlight each occurrence. Tried a lot of things.

```vb
    rangeFinding.SetRange Start:=rngStart.Start, End:=rngEnd.End
    rangeFinding.Select
    With Selection
        .Tables(1).cell(2, 2).Range.Text = y
    End With
    
    Dim qq As Range
    
    Set qq = GetCellTextRange(Selection.Tables(1).cell(2, 2))
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    
    With qq.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(\(*\))"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
    
        .Replacement.Font.Color = vbRed 
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
     
    qq.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
```

Procedure that is called:

```vb
Function GetCellTextRange(cl As cell) As Range ' ' GetCellTextRange
    returns the content range of a table cell '
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = cl.Range
    rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    Set GetCellTextRange = rng
End Function
```

Changing font color and/or bold does work, however highlighting not. Even when I replace `\1` with `YYY` it works. But highlighting does not get applied, either when I use `.Replacement.Highlight` or alternative `qq.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow`.

BTW: does the `Find` (and its `Execute`) function adapt `qq` range? That is what I noticed, but the docs do not tell it clearly.

Comment: `does the Find (and its Execute) function adapt qq range?` - if you were to find or replace one by one, then yes, `qq` would collapse to the current found element. With `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` it stays what it was in the beginning.

Comment: rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 should be rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -2 - the "end of cell marker" in Word is two characters, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with wildcard search/replace in VBA code not highlighting text. I was able to work around it by explicitly setting the default highlight colour before running the wildcard search/replace, and then setting it back to whatever it was afterward, e.g.:

```
currentHighlightColour = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(\{\{placeholder: *\}\})"
        .Format = True
        .replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .matchWildcards = True
        .matchCase = False
        .replacement.Highlight = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = currentHighlightColour
```

Seems like a bug in Word, but at least there's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that later.